# What is the meaning of "complacent acceptance"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

From what I understand by *"complacent acceptance"*, is that, someone accepts something without a doubt or without any cross questioning.

Is my understanding correct or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost exactly right about the meaning of complacent - which is used in a broad range of contexts with very similar effect. Typically the meaning is that the "complacent" person has assumed something - usually, something to their comfort or advantage - without examining the details of the situation. For example:

The factory owner had been complacent about the safety of his processes.

The politician complacently expected that she would be re-elected in the coming vote.

You don't give any context for the phrase "complacent acceptance", but the meaning is the same - assume things are OK, without checking. One of my friends regretted his complacent acceptance of a job contract, because the promised pay rise was not there in writing!

Answer (score 0):

There is no special meaning.  It is [acceptance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/acceptance), that is [complacent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/complacent)

It seems to be a "nonce" expression.  It has been used only once, in the title of a [The Complacent Acceptance of Diversity: Human Resource Development in a Culturally Diverse Environment](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Complacent-Acceptance-of-Diversity%3A-Human-in-a-Bernier/e1676bb064ca8a0ceec1ca6af1d1e500b7376a81) about the inability of work organizations to achieve racial balance.